# Webbrowser is showing corners in rounded border

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I have following code -

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="mask" CornerRadius="20" Height="auto" Width="auto" BorderThickness="1"
    BorderBrush="Black">
                        <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Source="http://www.google.com" Margin="1" />
                </Border>
```

It is providing the rounded boundry, but the webbrowser contant is still showing corners. I want to clip the extra corner to the boundry.

Comment: Have you tried increase the webBrowser's margin?

Comment: @Nagg : yes, but I want to clip it. Margin is disturbing the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunaly the WPF WebBrowser isn't a proper WPF Control, even though it's in the System.Windows.Controls namespace. It's just a wrapper around the IE ActiveX Control. So you cant apply styles, clip its corners, change the Control Template, etc. All WPF can do with the WebBrowser is change its size and position.
I think there are some hacks out there, but it definitively wont be as easy as setting a property.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So as far as I remember, UIElement has Clip property so you can specify an element to clip

```
<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Source="http://www.google.com" Margin="1">
<WebBrowser.Clip>
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="mask" 
CornerRadius="20" Height="auto" 
Width="auto" BorderThickness="1" />
</WebBrowser.Clip>
</WebBrowser>
```

Comment: sorry boss, Webbrowser.Clip doesn't support Border property